# ImportError: No module named 'asgiref.base_layer'

Tags: python-3.x, redis, django-channels

I was trying django channel example from https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django but it throws error when i run command **daphne chat.asgi:channel_layer --port 8888** that **ImportError: No module named 'asgiref.base_layer'**. I already installed all packages which is required for this example.Below is my requirements.txt file

```
asgi-redis==0.13.1
asgiref==0.9
autobahn==0.12.1
channels==0.16.1
daphne==0.9.1
dj-database-url==0.4.0
Django==1.9.7
haikunator==1.0.1
msgpack-python==0.4.7
psycopg2==2.6.1
redis==2.10.5
six==1.10.0
Twisted==16.2.0
txaio==2.2.1
wheel==0.24.0
zope.interface==4.1.3
```

I am using redis-server 3.2.6 and python 3.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a newer version of `channels` installed than the [article uses](https://github.com/jacobian/channels-example/blob/master/requirements.txt), but an older version of `asgiref`. Try updating to the latest version `asgiref==1.0.0` to fix our issue.